# How to use provider with firestore by creating a cart , problem adding item

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to add items to my cart along with the provider.
Once I run this function it should add items to the card but it doesn't:

```
void addToCart(id, price, title, urlImage) {
    context
        .read<CartList>()
        .addToCart(productId: id, price: price, title: title, image: urlImage);
    context.read<CartList>().cart;
  }
```

**Here is the provider:**

```
class CartList extends ChangeNotifier{
  Map<String, CartModel>_cart = {};

  Map get cart => _cart;

  void addToCart({required String productId,price,title,image}){
    if(_cart.containsKey(productId)){
      cart.update(productId,(value)=> CartModel(key: value.productId,name:value.name,image:value.image,price:value.price,quantity: 1,totalPrice: value.totalPrice));
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is Cart model (there is no space to add the code):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your addToCart method. The addToCart method only updates an entry in the map when one is added with the specified id.

```
  void addToCart({required String productId,price,title,image}){
    // When a item is added to the cart that already exists, update quantity by one
    if(_cart.containsKey(productId)){
      _cart.update(productId,(value)=> CartModel(key: value.productId,name:value.name,image:value.image,price:value.price,quantity: value.quantity + 1,totalPrice: value.totalPrice));
    } 
    // If the item is not in the cart, add it
    else {
      _cart[productId] = CartModel(key: productId,name:title,image:image,price:price,quantity: 1,totalPrice: price);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

I have updated your addToCart method to add a new CartModel when there is no entry with the id passed in. If it found an already-added entry I have changed it slightly to add 1 to the previous quantity.

I would recommend to change the name from CartModel to ProductModel since the CartModel implies that it is the cart and not the actual product/item

Hope it helps